# xcrun notarytool fails with missing keychain item

Tags: keychain, xcrun, notarize

I am using `xcrun notarytool store-credentials` to set my credentials for the notarization process of my executable. I use the command below to store the credentials:

```
%xcrun notarytool store-credentials --apple-id $APPLE_ID_USER \
                                    --team-id XYZ --password \
                                    $APP_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD xyz.io --verbose
Credentials saved to keychain.
```

Running `xcrun notarytool submit` succeeds for just a few minutes and rerunning the same command on the same executable all of the sudden returns this:

```
xcrun notarytool submit ...
Conducting pre-submission checks for xyz.dmg and initiating connection to the Apple notary service...
Error: No Keychain password item found for profile: xyz.io

Run 'notarytool store-credentials' to create another credential profile.
Error: Process completed with exit code 69.
```

I can still see the item in the keychain. Any idea what this might be caused by?
I have a second Mac where the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? An [issue](https://github.com/electron/notarize/issues/92) on GitHub appears to track this.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet. Thanks a lot for the link. The issue I am having is not Electron related but I will keep an eye on it. At the end I believe I have a corrupt keychain.

Comment: I know it's been months, but any resolution here? I am having the same problem.